# OAuth2 access to Cosmos' WebHDFS in FIWARE Lab

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I've recently seen the access to Cosmos' WebHDFS in FIWARE Lab has been protected with OAuth2. I know I have to add a OAuth2 token to the request in order to continue using WebHDFS, but:

- How can I get the token?
- How the token is added to the request?

Without the token, the API always returns:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/gtorodelvalle?op=liststatus&user.name=gtorodelvalle"
Auth-token not found in request header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, now WebHDFS access is protected with OAuth2. This is part of the general mechanism for pretecting REST APIs in FIWARE, which performs authentication and authorization. You can find more details [here](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/PEP_Proxy_-_Wilma_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide).

First of all, you must request an OAuth2 token to the Cosmos tokens generator. This is a service running in `cosmos.lab.fiware.org:13000`. You can do this using any REST client, the easiest way is using the curl command:

```
$ curl -k -X POST "https://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=frb@tid.es&password=xxxxxxxx"
{"access_token": "qjHPUcnW6leYAqr3Xw34DWLQlja0Ix", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "V2Wlk7aFCnElKlW9BOmRzGhBtqgR2z"}
```

As you can see, your FIWARE Lab credentials are required in the payload, in the form of a password-based grant type.

Once the access token is got (in the example above, it is `qjHPUcnW6leYAqr3Xw34DWLQlja0Ix`), simply add it to the same WebHDFS request you were performing in the past. The token is added by using the `X-Auth-Token` header:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/frb/path/to/the/data?op=liststatus&user.name=frb" -H "X-Auth-Token: qjHPUcnW6leYAqr3Xw34DWLQlja0Ix"
{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[...]}}
```

If you try the above request with a random token the server will return the token is not valid; that's because you have **not authenticated properly**:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/frb/path/tp/the/data?op=liststatus&user.name=frb" -H "X-Auth-Token: randomtoken93487345"
User token not authorized
```

The same way, if using a valid token but trying to access another HDFS userspace, you will get the same answer; that's because you are **not authorized** to access any HDFS userspace but the one owned by you:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/fgalan/path/tp/the/data?op=liststatus&user.name=fgalan" -H "X-Auth-Token: qjHPUcnW6leYAqr3Xw34DWLQlja0Ix"
User token not authorized
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

From summer 2016, `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` is not workin anymore. Instead, a pair of clusters, `storage.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org` have been setup. Regarding the auth server of Cosmos, it currently run in `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org`, port TCP/13000.

Comment: Why using `X-Auth-Token` (an OpenStack header) instead of using the header used in the OAuth2 standard: `Authorization`?

Comment: We are using FIWARE PEP Proxy in the middle (https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy). That component specifies the usage of `X-Auth-Token` in this piece of documentation: https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy#how-to-use.

Answer (score 1):

The right request must be:

curl -X POST "https://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=user@domain.com&password=yourpassword" -k

The url was incorrect, the correct is https://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:13000

-k is for turn off certificate verification

Comment: You are right with the `-k` option, I forgot to put it (thanks!). Regarding the endpoint, both `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` and `cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org` are resolved to the same IP address.

Comment: Using -k is considered extremely bad practice for anything other than local development. When will fi-ware install a third-party validated ssl cert?