# How to get a valid oauth2 token in Cosmos?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

My [Cosmos profile](https://cosmos.lab.fiware.org/profile) is:

```
IdM username:      <IDM_USERNAME>
Cosmos username:   <COSMOS_USERNAME>
Password:          <PASSWORD>
HDFS quota:        5
HDFS used:         0
Registration time: Fri Oct 23 2015 12:59:39 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Last access time:  0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

When I try to get a valid token with cUrl:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=<IDM_USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>"
```

I receive this error message:

```
{"error": {"message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}
```

How to get a valid oauth2 token in Cosmos?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187977/oauth2-access-to-cosmos-webhdfs-in-fiware-lab). You must use both your IdM username and password when asking for the token. Cosmos password is just for ssh access to the cluster.